# Two domain names pointing to one host

Tags: php, redirect, dns, hosting, host

I have two domain names and only one host. The fact is that my host doesn't accept multiple domain names. I asked to the support of my host how can I do and they gave me a part of code. My problem is that this code is not working for me. Can someone help me please?

```
<?php

$host = getenv('HTTP_HOST');

if($host == "www.domain1.ch"){
    header("Location: http://www.domain1.ch/index1.htm");
}

else if($host == "www.domain2.ch"){
    header("Location: http://www.domain2.ch/subfolder2/index.htm");
}
?>
```

On my admin panel of my host, I define a redirection of my second domain name to
a php page that contain this code.

Thank you in advance,

Nicolas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<?php

$host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

if($host == "www.domain1.ch"){
    header("Location: http://www.domain1.ch/index1.htm");
}

else if($host == "www.domain2.ch"){
    header("Location: http://www.domain2.ch/subfolder2/index.htm");
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you Satish, I thought I tried this yesterday but there was probably a mistake. It seems to work but now firefox and chrome are telling me that there was to much redirect so they can't display the site...

Comment: r u calling this on `index1.htm` because of calling on the every page every time you are redirecting using `header`

Comment: of course you're right! If I entered with the first domain name, it was always pointing on the same page. I think it will work like this. Thanks.